# How to create small files while inserting data to hive ORC table using TEZ

Tags: hive, orc, apache-tez

I have tried few options but I have only seen config settings to merge small files to big files like below but not vice versa.I am looking to create files of size 150kb .

```
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=128000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting ORC block size `hive.exec.orc.default.block.size`. Also to skip merging of small files, you will need to disable flag.
`set hive.merge.tezfiles=false;` You can refer [Hortonworks community thread link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/102379/how-files-loaded-through-a-hive-table-can-be-deter.html) for more information on how files are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below settings, these should help in keeping small files:

```
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=128000;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=100;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=128000;
set hive.exec.orc.default.block.size=128000;
```